# Rxjs - How can I extract multiple values inside an array and feed them back to the observable stream synchronously

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have created a `Rx.Observable` from a stream of events:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(recognizeStream, 'data')
```

In which every data event looks like this:

```
{ error: null, alternatives: [result1, result2, result3] }
```

I want to pluck every value inside the array of `alternatives` and merge those into the stream. What [operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) do I have to look at?

As far as I know the `flatMap` and `concatMap` could do the job but I don't get the idea from their example.

Can somebody explain which operator i should use and provide me with an example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The family of `xxxMap()` operators all deal with higher-order Observables. Which means they allow you to create Observables inside the main Observable and inline the resulting values into the primary stream. So you could read the type signature as `Observable<Observable<T>> => Observable<T>`

Given a stream which every emission *x* is an Observable containing 4 value emissions:

```
input:  --x----------x 
flatMap   a-a-a-a-|  b-b-b-b-|
result: --a-a-a-a----b-b-b-b-|
```

## Typecasting xxxMap(myFnc) return values

The `xxxMap()` operators all work with results of type `Observable`, `Promise` or `Array`. Depending on what you put into it will get converted to Observable if needed.

```js
Rx.Observable.of('')
  .flatMap(() => [1,2,3,4])
  .subscribe(val => console.log('array value: ' + val));

Rx.Observable.of('')
  .flatMap(() => Promise.resolve(1))
  .subscribe(val => console.log('promise value: ' + val));

Rx.Observable.of('')
  .flatMap(() => Promise.resolve([1,2,3,4]))
  .subscribe(val => console.log('promise array value: ' + val));

Rx.Observable.of('')
  .flatMap(() => Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4]))
  .subscribe(val => console.log('Observable value: ' + val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

In your case you can easily flatMap the objects and return the arrays:

```js
Rx.Observable.of({ error: null, alternatives: ['result1', 'result2', 'result3'] })
  .flatMap(val => val.alternatives)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

## Difference between all xxxMap operators

### What does mergeMap do

[`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html), better known as *`mergeMap`* will [`merge`](http://rxmarbles.com/#merge) all emissions whenever they come into the main stream.

[image]

### concatMap

concatMap will wait for all emissions to complete before [`concat`](http://rxmarbles.com/#concat) the next stream:

[image]

### switchMap

but switchMap will **abandon** the previous stream when a new emission is available and *switch* to emit values from the new stream:

[image]

Comment: Your youtube link is broken :(

Comment: Sorry to hear, i have updated my answer to clarify a bit about higher-order observables instead of linking to the missing movie

Comment: Am I right when guessing that concatMap(func) is the same as mergeMap(func, 1) (i.e. concurrency limited to 1)? ... Ah yes I'm right it's even mentioned in the docs :-), see http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap

Comment: A really nice write-up, way better than the docs. You saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

You should **pluck** "*alternatives*" then to iterate over the array use **from**, as **from** creates a new observable you need to flatten up it, so use you need flatMap to do the job. So finally you have *alternatives* back into the stream.

try it:

```js
var data = {
  error: null,
  alternatives: [{
    result: 1
  }, {
    result: 2
  }, {
    result: 3
  }]
}

var input$ = Rx.Observable.of(data);
input$.pluck('alternatives').flatMap(alternatives => Rx.Observable.from(alternatives)).subscribe(alternative => console.log(alternative));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `pluck` operator is a bit redundant if you still need to use `flatMap` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Operators `flatMap()` and `concatMap()` are both a good choice. You can just turn the `alternatives` property to another Observable and then emit the array items merged into the stream.

const Observable = Rx.Observable;

```
Observable.of({ error: null, alternatives: ['result1', 'result2', 'result3'] })
  .concatMap(val => {
    return Observable.from(val['alternatives']);
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This prints to console:

```
result1
result2
result3
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/foqutab/2/edit?js,console

Comment: What is the purpose of adding `return Observable.from(val['alternatives'])` inside `concatMap` rather than `return val.alternatives`. I had tried it and still be able to subscribe to the observable as well.

Comment: Returning `Observable.from` is universal and works with both RxJS 4 and RxJS 5. returning just an array works only in RxJS 5.