# What are use cases for mergeMap operator?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I don't understand the purpose of `mergeMap` at all. I have heard are two explanations:

1. It's like `SelectAll()` in .NET LINQ - nope.
2. It's a combination of RxJS `merge` and `map` - nope (or I can't replicate this).

Consider the [following code](http://jsbin.com/bipogaqepi/1/edit?html,js,console):

```
    var obs1 = new Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
    var obs2 = new Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
    
    //Just a merge and a map, works fine
    obs1.merge(obs2).map(x=> x+'a').subscribe(
      next => console.log(next)
    )
    
    //Who know what - seems to do the same thing as a plain map on 1 observable
    obs1.mergeMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val + `B`))
        .subscribe(
          next => console.log(next)
        )
```

The last piece labelled "Who knows what" does nothing more than a map on `obs1` - what's the point?

What does `mergeMap` actually do? What is an example of a valid use case? (Preferably with some code)

Articles that didn't help me at all (mergeMap code from above is from one of these): [1](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-mergeMap), [2](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**tl;dr;** `mergeMap` is way more powerful than `map`. Understanding `mergeMap` is the necessary condition to access full power of Rx.

---

### similarities

- both `mergeMap` and `map` acts on a single stream (vs. `zip`, `combineLatest`)
- both `mergeMap` and `map` can transform elements of a stream (vs. `filter`, `delay`)

### differences

#### map

- cannot change size of the source stream (assumption: `map` itself does not `throw`); for each element from source exactly one `mapped` element is emitted; `map` cannot ignore elements (like for example `filter`);
- in case of the default scheduler the transformation happens synchronously; to be 100% clear: the source stream may deliver its elements asynchronously, but each next element is immediately `mapped` and re-emitted further; `map` cannot shift elements in time like for example `delay`
- no restrictions on return values
- `id`: `x => x`

#### mergeMap

- can change size of the source stream; for each element there might be arbitrary number (0, 1 or many) of new elements created/emitted
- it offers full control over asynchronicity - both when new elements are created/emitted and how many elements from the source stream should be processed concurrently; for example assume source stream emitted 10 elements but `maxConcurrency` is set to 2 then two first elements will be processed immediately and the rest 8 buffered; once one of the processed `complete`d the next element from source stream will be processed and so on - it is bit tricky, but take a look at the example below
- all other operators can be implemented with just `mergeMap` and `Observable` constructor
- may be used for recursive async operations
- return values has to be of Observable type (or Rx has to know how to create observable out of it - e.g. promise, array)
- `id`: `x => Rx.Observable.of(x)`

### array analogy

```
let array = [1,2,3]
fn             map                    mergeMap
x => x*x       [1,4,9]                error /*expects array as return value*/
x => [x,x*x]   [[1,1],[2,4],[3,9]]    [1,1,2,4,3,9]
```

The analogy does not show full picture and it basically corresponds to `.mergeMap` with `maxConcurrency` set to 1. In such a case elements will be ordered as above, but in general case it does not have to be so. The only guarantee we have is that emission of new elements will be order by their position in the underlying stream. For example: `[3,1,2,4,9,1]` and `[2,3,1,1,9,4]` are valid, but `[1,1,4,2,3,9]` is not (since `4` was emitted after `2` in the underlying stream).

### A couple of examples using `mergeMap`:

```js
// implement .map with .mergeMap
Rx.Observable.prototype.mapWithMergeMap = function(mapFn) {
  return this.mergeMap(x => Rx.Observable.of(mapFn(x)));
}

Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
  .mapWithMergeMap(x => x * x)
  .subscribe(x => console.log('mapWithMergeMap', x))

// implement .filter with .mergeMap
Rx.Observable.prototype.filterWithMergeMap = function(filterFn) {
  return this.mergeMap(x =>
    filterFn(x) ?
    Rx.Observable.of(x) :
    Rx.Observable.empty()); // return no element
}

Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
  .filterWithMergeMap(x => x === 3)
  .subscribe(x => console.log('filterWithMergeMap', x))

// implement .delay with .mergeMap 
Rx.Observable.prototype.delayWithMergeMap = function(delayMs) {
  return this.mergeMap(x =>
    Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
      // setTimeout is naive - one should use scheduler instead
      const token = setTimeout(() => {
        obs.next(x);
        obs.complete();
      }, delayMs)
      return () => clearTimeout(token);
    }))
}

Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
  .delayWithMergeMap(500)
  .take(2)
  .subscribe(x => console.log('delayWithMergeMap', x))

// recursive count
const count = (from, to, interval) => {
  if (from > to) return Rx.Observable.empty();
  return Rx.Observable.timer(interval)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      count(from + 1, to, interval)
      .startWith(from))
}

count(1, 3, 1000).subscribe(x => console.log('count', x))

// just an example of bit different implementation with no returns
const countMoreRxWay = (from, to, interval) =>
  Rx.Observable.if(
    () => from > to,
    Rx.Observable.empty(),
    Rx.Observable.timer(interval)
    .mergeMap(() => countMoreRxWay(from + 1, to, interval)
      .startWith(from)))

const maxConcurrencyExample = () =>
  Rx.Observable.range(1,7)
    .do(x => console.log('emitted', x))
    .mergeMap(x => Rx.Observable.timer(1000).mapTo(x), 2)
    .do(x => console.log('processed', x))
    .subscribe()

setTimeout(maxConcurrencyExample, 3100)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.1.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @arturgrzesiak What if I used `mergeMap` for every basic curd operation ? does it effect around performance wise or some other?  I didn't try it,just got a doubt.

Comment: @k11k2 sorry for a late reply - like 3 years ago I had similar doubts, since then I have been building whole apps as single observable and Rx performance was never an issue.

Comment: so this is how that works. The completely non-human readable explanation on the RxJs docs should be replaced with this.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap
wtf m8?

Answer (score 24):

`.mergeMap()` lets you flatten a higher-order Observable into a single stream. For instance:

```js
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4])
  .map(i => getFreshApiData())
  .subscribe(val => console.log('regular map result: ' + val));

//vs

Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4])
  .mergeMap(i => getFreshApiData())
  .subscribe(val => console.log('mergeMap result: ' + val));

function getFreshApiData() {
  return Rx.Observable.of('retrieved new data')
    .delay(1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.1.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

See my answer at this other question for an in-dept explanation of the `.xxxMap()` operators: [Rxjs - How can I extract multiple values inside an array and feed them back to the observable stream synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997883/rxjs-how-can-i-extract-multiple-values-inside-an-array-and-feed-them-back-to-t/42006671#42006671)