# catch error and emit different action when handling ngrx-effects

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

In the code snippet below, I want to emit a `GetData` action if the update operation was successful or a `BackendError` action if unsuccessful.

```
@Effect()
updateData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(MyActionType.UPDATE_DATA),
  map((action: UpdateData) => action.payload),
  combineLatest(this.authService.getUser(), (myData, user) => this.dataService.updateData(myData, user)),
  map(() => new GetData()),
  catchError((err) => { of(new BackendError(err)))
);
```

The above code does not seem to be working.  Even though the update operation fails due to permission error, the `BackendError` action is not emitted.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation will swallow errors on the `updateData` operation, because the `action$` (the outer observable) gets mapped to a `new GetData()` action, regardless of the result of the `updateData` operation (success or failure).

In the implementation below, the `catchError` operator will runif the `updateData` operation (`dataUpdate$` -- the inner observable) throws an error..

```
@Effect()
updateData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(MyActionType.UPDATE_DATA),
  mergeMap((action: UpdateData) => {
    const user$ = this.authService.getUser();
    const dataUpdate$ = user$.pipe(
      mergeMap(user => this.dataService.updateData(action.payload, user));
    );
    return dataUpdate$.pipe(
      map(() => new GetData()),
      catchError(err => of(new BackendError(err)))
    );
  })
);
```

---

**Additional Resources**

1. Here's some more information on the [difference between `mergeMap`
   and `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42272148/5932590).
2. Official docs for [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap).
3. Example of `@Effect` using this approach in the [`@ngrx/effects` README](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Vince.  Your snippet is missing a value for user which is required by `dataService.updateData()`.  I have modified it as `dataUpdate$=this.authService.getUser().map(user => this.dataService.updateData(action.payload, user))`, but BackendError action is still not emitted.  I have tried to enclose call to `updateData()` in `Observable.fromPromise()` as the `updateData()` method returns a promise, but that did not work either.

Comment: No problem! I edited my answer to reflect what you're trying to do. I think you just need another `mergeMap` instead of `map`. See my updated answer and let me know if that works for you.