# Conditionally merge rxjs array responses into a single array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, spotify

In my Angular 6 service, I have the following method to get the current user's first 50 playlists from the Spotify Web API:

```
getPlaylists(accessToken: string): Observable<Playlist[]> {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    })
  };

  return this.httpClient.get<Playlist[]>('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists?limit=50', httpOptions)
    .pipe(map((response: any) => response.items));
}
```

This works well enough if the current user only has 50 playlists or fewer.

However, if a user has more than 50 playlists, the Spotify Web API limits the number of playlists in a single response to 50, and instead the `response` object contains a `next` property, which is the URI for the endpoint to request the next 50 playlists.

I would like to extend the `getPlaylists` function to get *all* of a user's playlists, i.e.: as long as the `response` object contains a valid `next` property, I'd like to keep sending `GET` requests to the URI it contains, and finally merge the resulting `response.items` arrays so that the  function returns a single `Observable<Playlist[]>`.

How would I go about doing so?

Thanks!

*EDIT: The Spotify Web API endpoint I'm using is https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists/*

Comment: I doubt it is the fastest way to do it, but you could do a recursion checking for the next object. Another way would be to forkjoin on two queries first, asking for offset 0 and offset 50 (cf. API), and check if the second query returns results.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [.mergeMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) which helps you to flatten your high-order Observable into a single stream.

Simple Example of Hello World

```js
//emit 'Hello'
const source = Rx.Observable.of('Hello');
//map to inner observable and flatten
const example = source.mergeMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(`${val} World!`));
//output: 'Hello World!'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.1.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

To have better understanding between `.map()` and `.mergeMap()`- check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120680/how-does-rxjs-mergemap-work) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42272148/6426617)