# How can I have only X observables active at a time?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

> I'm using RxJS v6, but the answer could apply to RxJS v5 as well.

I'd like to make it so if I have say 8 values, I would only have 4 actively being processed at a time.

The code I have right now sends in 4 items, then waits till all 4 finish, then sends in the next 4. I'd like it to send in the first 4, then as an observable completes, another one comes in to be processed.

```js
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
.pipe(
    bufferCount(4),
    concatMap(values => (
        from(values)
        .pipe(
            mergeMap(value => (
                timer(1000) // Async stuff would happen here
                .pipe(
                    mapTo(value),
                )
            )),
        )
    )),
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the second parameter of `mergeMap`, which is a number that allows to specify the *concurrency* *level* you want.

So your code could look like

```
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
.pipe(
    map(val => of(val)),
    mergeMap(val => val, 4),
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

or

```
of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
.pipe(
    mergeMap(val => val, 4),
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Consider that `concatMap` is `mergeMap` with concurrency level set to 1.

Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120680/how-does-rxjs-mergemap-work/42122031) for more details on `mergeMap`.

Comment: I ended up looking up `concatMap`'s source and saw exactly what you said. I didn't know the second arg was optional though.