# Worthiest way to wait until first observable complete to do the second subscribe logic?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactivex

I was wondering the best way to achieve this.

If i have two observables **A** & **B**, and i want to process the **next** **B** logic after the **A** has completed his **next** logic.

I'm currently using combineLatest for that purpose.

Any best choice?

Thanks!

Comment: Theres heaps of ways to do this and there is no 'best' way if how your doing it works, leave it at that.

Comment: look at mergeMap operator, combineLatest is Promise.all but your order matters hence should not be using it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Does RxJS MergeMap Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120680/how-does-rxjs-mergemap-work)

Comment: One thing to note with `combineLatest` is that there is no way to impose an order of execution. It is going to trigger regardless of whether **A** or **B** is pushed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `b$.pipe(withLatestFrom(a$))`. This way you can see things clearly. But `combineLatest` works fine.