# Ionic 3 & Firebase - Proper way to nest observables

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs

Is there a more practical way to nest these observables with RX/JS. Here is a snippet, where I am storing an image first, then returning the download URL and placing it in the real time database.

```
return new Observable(observer => {
        firebase.storage().ref().child('users/' + this.userService.getUserID() + '/messages/').put(image).then((data) => {

          updates['photoURL'] = data.downloadURL;

          firebase.database().ref().update(updates).then(() => {
            observer.next();
            observer.complete();
          }).catch((error) => {
            observer.error(error);
          })
        }, (error) => {
          observer.error(error);
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use higher-order Observables and [their respective operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997883/rxjs-how-can-i-extract-multiple-values-inside-an-array-and-feed-them-back-to-t/42006671#42006671) to inline operations which depend on each other. For instance:

```
function uploadImageAndUpdateState(userId, image, updates) {
  return Observable.defer(() => firebase.storage().ref().child(`users/${userId}/messages/`).put(image))
    .mergeMap(imagePutData => {
      updates['photoURL'] = imagePutData.downloadURL;
      return firebase.database().ref().update(updates;
    });
});
```

By using `Defer()` on the image put (promise) this Observable will start after subscribing to `uploadImageAndUpdateState` to upload the image, after receiving data from that operation modify the `updates` and update that as well in firebase. Since your example contained no error handling (only propagation) this is not done in this function, you still need to handle that yourself in your `subscribe(.., onError => ???)` logic.

Comment: Is there a potential downside or unwanted behavior from the code  the way it is in the snippet?

Comment: Downsides of the code per the questions snippet: no cancellation support, bit messy & superfluous due to the use of low-abstraction methods (`new Observable` // `Observable.create()` vs `Observable.from()` // `Observable.defer()` // ...

Comment: If it is just a singular call to firebase, are the low methods acceptable such as within this tutorial?

http://masteringionic.com/blog/2017-03-06-uploading-images-to-firebase-storage-with-ionic-part-2/

Comment: Even though `Observable.create` [just wraps `new Observable()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/MiscJSDoc.js.html#lineNumber129) the former is preferred. But that is just syntax. It will work. As stated in my previous comment; you are not gaining all the benefits you could get from Observables if you should use more suitable functions to compose the behaviour you search.

Comment: Are there any patterns to follow when nesting three firebase calls or N api calls for a more general case?